# Why is the structure of my ruby project like this and why use load path?

Tags: ruby

I am using an old, 2010 book called "the rspec book" to learn rspec and cucumber. PLEASE DON'T tell me how old this book is and that ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 are outdated. I have not yet seen any beginner book like this which uses latest ruby.

**The current structure of my project named "codebreaker":**

```
.
├── features
│   ├── codebreaker_starts_game.feature
│   ├── codebreaker_submits_guess.feature
│   ├── step_definitions
│   │   └── codebreaker_steps.rb
│   └── support
│       └── env.rb
└── lib
    ├── codebreaker
    │   └── game.rb
    └── codebreaker.rb
```

**Here is the code and notes from the book:**

/features/step_definitions/codebreaker_steps.rb

```
Given /^I am not yet playing$/ do
end
When /^I start a new game$/ do
Codebreaker::Game.new.start
end
```

/lib/codebreaker/game.rb

```
module Codebreaker
 class Game
  def start
  end
 end
end
```

If you run cucumber now, you’ll see the error `uninitialized constant Codebreaker (NameError)` because Cucumber isn’t loading game.rb yet. The conventional approach to this is to have
a file in the lib directory named for the top-level module of the app. In our case, that’s codebreaker.rb . Create that file now, with the following:

/lib/codebreaker.rb

```
require 'codebreaker/game'
```

Now add the following to features/support/env.rb:

```
$LOAD_PATH << File.expand_path( '../../../lib' , __FILE__)
require 'codebreaker'
```

> Cucumber will load features/support/env.rb , which now requires
>   lib/codebreaker.rb , which, in turn, requires lib/codebreaker/game.rb
>   , which is where we defined the Codebreaker module with the Game with
>   an empty start () method. If you now run cucumber
>   features/codebreaker_starts_game.feature , you should see some
>   different results.

**My question:** Why do we have this `env.rb` and why does it not point directly to `lib/codebreaker/game.rb` ? Why go through `lib/codebreaker.rb`. It makes no sense to me. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your app currently stands it wouldn't make any difference.

With a real project there would be many more files though and you would require them through lib/codebreaker.rb so that  users  of your library just need to require the one file.

You wouldn't want to duplicate that list of requires in env.rb, so your specs load lib/codebreaker.rb, just like any other user of your library.

Comment: Thanks ! I am guessing that, when you execute `cucumber features' from project root directory, cucumber looks for all code only in a "default" directory called `features`. The env.rb file provides pointers to other places where source code can be found. Is this correct ? If right, then can you please tell me why cucumber does not look in lib folder as well ?

Comment: Btw, is there any other way to load all the code in a project, besides just using a "pointer" file like `env.rb`. Thank you.

Comment: Cucumber does add lib to the load path. It doesn't automatically require everything in there because that isn't always the right thing to do (for example maybe some files need to be required in a specific order or one group of files should only be loaded when running windows or a specific version of ruby). You could use Dir.glob to iterate over all your files and require them but you'll probably run into those same issues later on